# Lower SERP rankings when signed in

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, search-results

When I check one of our site's rankings when signed in, I get lower rankings for my own site than the rankings I would get while signed out.

If anything, it should have been the other way round?

Any possible reasons?

Thanks

(Not duplicate, please take a minute to understand the question rather than rushing to a quick judgement)

Comment: Signed into what?

Comment: Using Google search while signed into chrome or signed into google account.

Comment: Sorry KBS this question has been asked several times in various forms already on Pro Webmasters. You should always check search results without being logged in (the best way to do this is Ctrl+Shift+N in Google Chrome).

Comment: Please read the question again. I know results can be different if you're logged in but my question is why rankings are lower when they should have been higher for my own site??